# What's Kolmogorov's russian name?

Tags: перевод, произношение, ономастика

I know that the title is a little weird, sorry about that. The thing is that one day I asked my russian instructor, who's russian, how to pronounce Kolmogorov in russian (because it has too many o's) and she told me that is *Холмогóров*, but in the [wiki article](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) says that his name is *Колмогóров*, why is this?

Comment: That's just a mistake, the real last name of the famous Soviet mathematician is _Колмогóров_.

Comment: Check that you can pronounce Чебыщев and Чеботарев correctly too. At least in English these mathematician names are not close to the native pronunciation.

Comment: @KCd did you mean Чебышев?

Comment: @Anixx: yes, I did.

Comment: By the way, the correct spelling of Чебышев is Чебышёв, so it is pronounced "chee-bih-SHOFF".

Comment: @YellowSky: I know the names are more accurately Чебышёв and Чеботарёв, but (1) е is used for ё in writing so often that I don't think Чебышев is really wrong, (2) part of the point of my comment was precisely that a reader will encounter the names in the form Чебышев and Чеботарев, and (3) I was writing my first comment on a tablet, where the Cyrillic keyboard didn't have ё available.

Comment: @KCd - That's OK, no problem, I didn't mean you were wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Russian teacher was not a mathematician, so she probably guessed that the name is "kholmogorov", as there is a Russian word "kholm" meaning a hill.

The correct name is Kolmogorov, and you pronounce it roughly as "Kalmagoraf"

Comment: Among the population in Russia outside of science, would you say that Kolmogorov is not widely known?

Comment: @KCd - No, he isn't.

Comment: I guess he's not, which is amusing, because he wrote the high school calculus textbook. Now, in Russia teachers can't use any textbook they wish, they have to use approved ones, AND calculus is _compulsory_. So, there must be a generation of people who must have read his textbook, yet they don't know him.

Comment: @KCd: In my experience, most well-educated people in Russia know Kolmogorov. Perhaps, Lobachevsky, Chebyshev and Kovalevskaya are even more widely known but other Russian mathematicians are less known than Kolmogorov. (I would say that Kolmogorov is more widely known in Russia than Richard Feynman is in the US.)

Comment: Kovalevskaya is more known than Kolmogorov? Oh my... that completely blown my mind!

Comment: I think that Kovalevskaya is definitely known more, as well as Lobachevsky. The deal with Kovalevskaya was that she fit the communist feminism narrative, in my opinion. The fact that she did some cool stuff didn't hurt her recognition either, while both her and Kolmogorov's bodies of work are well beyond high school curriculum. Functional analysis and measure theoretic probability is taught in college for math majors.

Answer (score 5):

Происхождение фамилии «Колмогоров» связано с топонимом «Колмогоры», а он, вероятно, происходит от финского kolme «три» (т. е. «Трехгорка»), или от kalma, «могила», и kari, «утес». «Холмогоры» – русификация
Происхождение от топонима
Кроме Колмогор (Холмогор) в Архангельской области, топоним известен в Кемеровской. Деревни Колмогорово также существуют в Сибири
Женская форма фамилии - Колмогорова.